# The Evaluation Map is Bilinear

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I was asked to prove the following: The evaluation map $\epsilon : V \times V^* \rightarrow \mathcal{F}$ such that $\epsilon(v, f) = f(v)$ is bilinear. Prove. 
However, it seems like it is impossible for this map to be bilinear. If f is fixed to the square root function, it follows that $\epsilon(f, av) = f(av) = \sqrt(av) \neq af(v) = a\sqrt(v)$, if $a \neq 1, 0$. How is this evaluation map a bilinear mapping then?

EDIT
I understand now, I'm not too sure how I made that mistake. Thanks!

Comment: The domain of $\epsilon$ is $V\times V^*$.  Why do you believe the square root function belongs to $V$?  Maybe it does, but you haven't told us what you mean when you write $V$.

Comment: You need to show two things:
1. $\epsilon(f,cv+w) = c\epsilon(f,v)+\epsilon(f,w)$
2. $\epsilon(cf+g,v)= c\epsilon(f,v)+\epsilon(g,v)$

Comment: You're assuming that the square root function is in $V^*$ -- however by definition $V^*$ is the space of all _linear_ functions $V\to F$, and $\sqrt{\phantom{a}}$ is not linear.

Comment: @ErickWong It did not specify which field V was over, but taking the field to be  the real numbers, is this not an issue? I feel like there must be something obvious I'm missing here.

Comment: @OpenBall Ah yes, I meant to say $V^*$.  The square root function could belong to $V^*$, I suppose, if $V$ is the $1$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb F_2$ :)

Comment: @Duncan Read Henning's comment.  Why do you believe the square root function over the reals is an element of the dual space of $V$?

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand. Presumably $V$ is a vector space and $V^*$ is its dual. In this case, any $f\in V^*$ is a linear map $f:V\to\mathcal F$, so by definition $f(av)=af(v)$ for all $a\in\cal F$. So the "square root function" is not even an example of a possible $f$.

The map is bilinear because if you take another $f'\in V^*$ and $a\in\cal F$, then

$$\epsilon(v,f+af')=(f+af')(v)=f(v)+af'(v)=\epsilon(v,f)+a\epsilon(v,f')$$

and if you have another $v'\in V$, then

$$\epsilon(v+av',f)=f(v+av')=f(v)+af(v')=\epsilon(v,f)+a\epsilon(v',f),$$

where we used the linearity of $f$.